# Can't convert String containing CET Time Zone to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone, nsdateformatter

So, I have the following Date string that commes from a Server:

`2020-05-09 18:33:00 CET`

So, in order to get a NSDate from that NSString I use the following code:

```
+(NSDate*) converFirebaseStringDateToDate:(NSString*)dateStr {    
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
return dateFromString;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, always the return `dateFromString` is NIL (as if the date format was invalid) which is not according to the documentation.. What am I missing here? This very same peace of code is working just fine with string like: `2020-05-09 16:26:33 GMT` or even `2020-05-09 12:35:02 EDT`

Also been trying to use `2020-05-09 18:33:00 CEST` as Input but still failing!

Comment: http://www.openradar.me/9944011#aglvcGVucmFkYXJyDwsSB0NvbW1lbnQYkf5UDA ?

Comment: Time zone abbreviations are not identifiers.  Many are ambiguous.  You will need to specify an [IANA time zone ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), such as `Europe/Paris`.